# Order event dispatch laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel

Hello I'm using redis and ioredis for frontend for handle real time event from laravel 5, so I have a queue:listen on my server, and the event are properly sent and received but I have a problem, if I have 3 event sent in row like:

```
Event::fire(new Status(1, "status1"));
Event::fire(new Status(2, "status2"));
Event::fire(new Status(3, "status3"));
```

The queue process in random order, and front end render (for example) "status3 ,status1, status2" or "status2 , status3, status1" instead of correct order of fire:
"status1, status2, status3", there is a method for order queue?

Comment: Async events are and will always be async, you could include a timestamp and use this to insert it in the correct place on the front end